# form labels not showing on html with a crispy form

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

I cannot find a way to make the labels of a form showing up in the template. I have been looking for hours on stackoverflow on ways to do it and nothing works so far. The labels are not showing up.

Maybe i have a mistake in my code somewhere but i am not able to to spot it.

forms.py

```
class Contact(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = contact
        fields = ['first_name','last_name','email','phone']
        #labels = {'first_name':'First name','last_name':'Last name', 'email':'email', 'phone':'phone number'}
        
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(Contact, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.helper = FormHelper()
            self.helper.form_show_labels = True
            self.fields['first_name'].label = "First name"
            self.fields['last_name'].label = "Last name"
            self.fields['email'].label = "email"
            self.fields['phone'].label = "phone number"
```

html template:

```
<p> {%  trans 'Or fill out the form below' %}</p> 
<form method="POST" class="form-validate" id="contact">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <a>{% crispy form %}
         <input type="submit" class="learn_more2" value={%  trans 'Contact us' %}  style="background-color:#36393f; color:#DB6574; margin:auto; display:block">
    </a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the crispy form tags with `{% load crispy_forms_tags %}`- so e.g. at the top of your template. Also crispy "replaces" the `<form> ...</form>`.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %} <!-- HERE -->

{% block title %}
    Title
{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% crispy form %}
{% endblock %}
```

something like this.